# Having a popup window able to update the main window

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list of items showed on a page. Each item can be clicked and opened in a popup window to be edited. On this popup window, I have a save button.

When this 'save' button is clicked, I would like:

- call an action controller to update the database
- close the popup window
- refresh the main list item (still opened in the background)

Can anyone help me to achieve this? I really don't know how to update the main window (list of items).

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353011/jquery-popup-window-return-value-to-parent. The implementation of the part where you `call an action controller to update the database` may depend - submitting the form (as in the referred question) seems like a reasonable approach.