# return back to parent window using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am popping out a child window from parent window.Now, in child window, I have a html form that a user will fill and submit and request will go on server site.Now, I wanted response to this request redirected to parent window and my child window automatically closed out.Hope I am clear enough. If not let me know. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [jQuery Popup Window Return Value to Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353011/jquery-popup-window-return-value-to-parent/2366824#2366824)

basically the logic can be:

1. You response returns a page that contains a hidden-div that contains the message you want to display (hidden with CSS set `display:none;`)
2. That child page returned also contains some JavaScript that fills in the parent window with the DIV content, `parent/* or opener */.document.getElementById(...).innerHTML = ...;`
   or calls a function on the parent to tell it it's now complete, like `window.opener/*or parent*/.formIsComplete();` where `formIsComplete()` is a JavaScript function in the parent document/window.
3. The last line of the JavaScript on the child window, will close itself, as simple as `window.close();`.

Answer (score 4):

If the pop-up window is created using `window.open`, then the pop-up window can access the opening window using `window.opener`.

On the main window, you have to create a function to receive data from the popup, something like this:

```
window.receiveDataFromPopup = function(data) {
    // do things with data.
};
```

Then in the pop-up window, you can call that function on the opener like this:

```
window.opener.receiveDataFromPopup(data);
```

To close the window, just use

```
window.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to access the parent window from the child. It is

```
window.opener //use window.opener to access the parent window.
```

So in the child window, once your form submission completes, just call

```
window.opener.yourFunc() //Your func is a function on parent. Call this from the child.
```

Once this function is called close your child window using

```
window.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.opener.location.reload();    
  window.close();
</script>
```