# Retrieve values from a pop up window to the parent window

Tags: javascript

I have a pop up window that contains some selections. Once the user selects options, the selected options need to be displayed in the main window. The main window doesn't need to be refreshed when options are selected from the pop up window. I'm using javascript for this, but I cannot figure out how to access the `checkbox` item of the pop up window from the main window.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Bike" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="car" />

var chbox = document.getElementById("vehicle[]").value;
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Check out [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353011/jquery-popup-window-return-value-to-parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you open the popup window..

If you open it with `window.open` then you can store the returned value from that command to a variable and use that to communicate with the window..

for example

```
var popup = window.open('url-here');
// you can use popup.document to access the DOM of the popup window..
alert( popup.document.getElementById('checkbox-id').value );
```

Comment: thanks.yeah im using window.open,but if there are more than one check  box selections can i pass it to an array an retrieve from the main window?  can you please give me an example, really appreciate you help.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="car" />

var chbox1 = document.yourform.vehicle[1].value;
var chbox2 = document.yourform.vehicle[2].value;
```

hope it will work for you ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean popup window opened using `window.open`?

if yes then this method returns new window-object. And you can use it to refer child(popup) window and tis properties.

This code will log into console(in firefox for example) all DOM elements from child window.

`var popup=window.open(...); console.log(popup.document.all);`

I hope it helps you