# popup window code

Tags: asp.net

i have 2 aspax page.
client.aspx
popup.aspx

client.aspx contains a simple registration form. in this form i have to take one of the textbox value from popup.aspx. that textbox contains with a search button

when i click on search button popup.aspx page is opened in a popup window.

in popup.aspx i m showing a grid contains productCode and product name and a select button.
when i select a row of grid then corresponding product name should be displyed in textbox. and tht popup window should be closed.

**Update**

```
    ImageButton imgbut = sender as ImageButton; 
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)imgbut.NamingContainer; 
    lblKeyIndex.Text =  grd_ProductMaster.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); 
    lblProductName.Text = gvr.Cells[2].Text; 
    Session["ProdName"] = lblProductName.Text;
    Server.Transfer("client_Master.aspx");
    Response.Write("<Script>window.close()</Script>");       Response.Redirect("client_Master.aspx?ProdName=" +        lblProductName.Text+"&ProdCode="+lblKeyIndex.Text)
```

on page load of client.aspx

```
if (Session["ProdName"] != null) 
{ 
 txtSelectProdName.Text = Session["ProdName"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is this a question... do you have code you have tried... if so please post it here.

Comment: what's your question? how to do all the functionality? or you have part of it?

Comment: What you have **tried** and what is your **problem**?

Comment: ImageButton imgbut = sender as ImageButton;
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)imgbut.NamingContainer;
            lblKeyIndex.Text = grd_ProductMaster.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            lblProductName.Text = gvr.Cells[2].Text;
            Session["ProdName"] = lblProductName.Text;
            Server.Transfer("client_Master.aspx");
            Response.Write("<Script>window.close()</Script>");
           
            Response.Redirect("client_Master.aspx?ProdName=" + lblProductName.Text+"&ProdCode="+lblKeyIndex.Text);

Comment: @user1280428: remove this comment and edit your question with the code :) also check your spellings as well please

Comment: on page load of client.aspx if (Session["ProdName"] != null)
            {
                txtSelectProdName.Text = Session["ProdName"].ToString();
            }

Comment: this code is working. but it is redirecting client.aspx in popup window. i dont want that

Comment: otherwise do one can u give me the code for how to access popup windows value in another aspx page without using response.redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Open a [pop-up window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

In your pop-up window try to [return the value to parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353011/jquery-popup-window-return-value-to-parent).

Comment: Note that most people coming to the site get here _from_ Google searches. There's no need to tell people to search Google.

Comment: @sarnold: do you really think the question asked here was out of google search? google didn't give any answer so he posted question here?? what I meant to say is split the problem and seach in google separately..

Comment: One person asks a question, and maybe dozens or hundreds of people come around to finding the answers later. We're not writing just for the questioner but also posterity. :)